# No changes on my phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ios7

I recently started using the phonegap desktop application which builds phonegap apps and sends them to the developer app. I was wondering why none of my config.xml changes are reflected in the built app? I have relaunch the builder and the dev app but neither registers a change.

I know the software is very new but if you have any thoughts I'd like to hear them.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run `cordova build`or `phonegap build` commands.

Cordova

```
cordova build android
cordova build ios
```

Phonegap

```
phonegap build android
phonegap build ios
```

Comment: How do I do this in phonegap the desktop app?

Comment: open your CMD/terminal. cd to your project and run this command. thats all.

Comment: no problem at all :)